# Часть речи - слово "еще"

Tags: синтаксис

Приведите примеры тех случаев, когда слово "еще" наречие или частица.

Comment: См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=Ещё+&all=x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B5%D1%89%D1%91&all=x)**

**ЕЩЁ. I. *нареч*.**

**1.** Дополнительно, вдобавок к тому же. *Налей е. стакан чаю. Съешь е. кусочек! В доме е. кто-нибудь есть? Скажи мне е. что-нибудь. Чего тебе е. надо? У него ревматизм и е. что-то.* // Снова, опять. *Попробуй позвонить е. раз. Приезжайте е., не забывайте нас! Во всём виноват ты и е. раз ты! Надо повторить опыты е. и е.*

**2.** До сих пор. *Пароход е. не причалил. Я е. не сплю. Письмо е. не отправлено. Он всё е. работает. Отец е. не приходил. Ты е. не читал сегодняшнюю газету?* // Пока что. *Он е. совершенный ребёнок. Малышу е. два года. Ты уже собрался? - Нет е.*

**3** (при обозначении времени, места). Уже. *Е. издалека мы увидели море. Дом построен е. в прошлом году. Письмо принесли е. вчера.*

**4.** Указывает на наличие возможности, достаточных оснований для совершения, осуществления чего-л. *Он е. будет учёным. Больной е. поправится. Мы е. будем жить счастливо.*

**5** (при сравнит. ст. прил. и нареч.). Более, в большей степени. *Это случилось е. раньше, чем мы предполагали. Речка стала е. мельче. Пирог с черникой е. вкуснее, чем с яблоками. Она редко улыбается, а смеётся е. реже.*

**II. *союз.*** Указывает на предположительность условия или на его соотносительность с чем-л.; в какой-то мере, хоть. *Ты е. счастливо отделался! По сравнению с нашим, ваш двор е. чистый. У вас тут е. тихо, не то, что у нас.*

**III. *частица*.**

**1.** Употр. при местоимениях и наречиях для подчёркивания какого-л. признака, факта, для придания выразительности высказываемому. *Когда он е. явится! Как е. рады-то будем! Ты Мишу не видел? - Какого е. Мишу?*

**2.** Употр. для уточнения, подчёркивания какого-л. признака, факта. *Помнишь, высокий такой, е. на заводе у нас работал? Там, где е. наличники на окнах резные, там он и живёт.* // (при уточнении времени действия). Не дальше как..., всего только. *Е. вчера я об этом и не думал. Е. только четыре часа, а уже светает.*